# Python. Open file > read line > open URLS from file

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python, but i am trying create my own desktop app for massive screenshots creating from urls link in TXT or others file and i stuck.

I stuck in file dialoge.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import webbrowser
root = Tk()
root.title("Name")
root.geometry("700x400")
def open_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfiles()
open_button = ttk.Button(text="Choose File", command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=295, pady=355, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

So did i get it right. I have filedialog.askopenfiles() for file dialoge (choose files) and i need add line read from my file, coz i need python see URLS and read it, after that i need import webbrowser and loop all line for TXT or other files urls to open it on my browser.

But i really cant get it.. How i can link webbrowser+ urls from my txt file and open all web-site

After that i need make a screenchots for each website.

Can anybody help with, at least, with openingn all links from file i choose in file dialoge.

Sorry for my bad english, i hope you get it.

Comment: You have to do something with `filepath` after asking for it with the file dialog. There are many tutorials on how to read from files.

Comment: I know about tutorials. I can read files if i create script just for read 1 file, but i cant do it when i use filedialog.askopenfiles() any hint?

Comment: `askopenfiles()` doesn't return the pathnames, it opens the files. Just loop over the results and start reading them. `for file in filepath: print(file.read())`